# Creating symlinks with ansible using variables

Tags: ansible, symlink

I'm doing a playbook to create symlinks of nodejs, npm and gulp because I need to use a specific version and to install it all I'm just unzipping folders to /opt/ where all this is going to stay.

The task with items I'm using for creating the links are:

```
- name: Create NPM symlink
  file:
    src: '{{ item.src_dir }}/{{ item.src_name }}'
    dest: '{{ item.dest_dir }}/{{ item.dest_name }}'
    owner: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    group: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    state: link
  with_items:
    - { src_dir: "{{ npm_real_dir }}", src_name: "{{ npm_real_name }}" }
    - { dest_dir: "{{ nodenpm_link_dir }}", dest_name: "{{ npm_link_name }}" }
```

all the variables used in the items "zone" are declared in the host file as such:
`npm_real_dir=/opt/nodejs/node-v6.11.2-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/bin`

`npm_real_name=npm-cli.js`

`nodenpm_link_dir=/opt/nodejs/node-v6.11.2-linux-x64/bin`

`npm_link_name=npm`

`ansible_ssh_user=vagrant`

And I'm getting the error:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'dest_dir'
```

Which I'm not understanding since all the variables used in the task are declared and correct. I made a similar task without items:

```
- name: Create symbolic link for npm
  file:
    src: '{{ npm_real_dir }}/{{ npm_real_name }}'
    path: '{{ nodenpm_link_dir }}/{{ npm_link_name }}'
    owner: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    group: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    state: link
```

And its working, however the structure is the same as before, just without the items.

At this point I just want to know if its a known bug, if there is any issue in using items to create links, or if I did a stupid mistake and gain knowledge about it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing two different objects to the `with_items` property. The first object has two properties (`src_dir` and `src_name`), while the second object has two different properties (`dest_dir` and `dest_name`).

It looks like you want to combine them into a single object like this:

```
- name: Create NPM symlink
  file:
    src: '{{ item.src_dir }}/{{ item.src_name }}'
    dest: '{{ item.dest_dir }}/{{ item.dest_name }}'
    owner: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    group: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    state: link
  with_items:
    - { src_dir: "{{ npm_real_dir }}", src_name: "{{ npm_real_name }}", dest_dir: "{{ nodenpm_link_dir }}", dest_name: "{{ npm_link_name }}" }
```

That should work better and get rid of the error, but in this case you don't really need the `with_items`, since it's only one item that you're dealing with. You can add more objects for other tools, e.g. `gulp` in the same manner, e.g. like this:

```
- name: Create symlinks
  file:
    src: '{{ item.src_dir }}/{{ item.src_name }}'
    dest: '{{ item.dest_dir }}/{{ item.dest_name }}'
    owner: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    group: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
    state: link
  with_items:
    - { src_dir: "{{ npm_real_dir }}", src_name: "{{ npm_real_name }}", dest_dir: "{{ nodenpm_link_dir }}", dest_name: "{{ npm_link_name }}" }
    - { src_dir: "{{ gulp_real_dir }}", src_name: "{{ gulp_real_name }}", dest_dir: "{{ gulp_link_dir }}", dest_name: "{{ gulp_link_name }}" }
```

Comment: oh ok. makes sence about an undefined variable when you are not even passing it. Thanks for your answer :)